# centos-7 missing /dev/net/tap

Tags: tap, net, dev

Going `ls -l /dev/net` shows the `tun` device (device 10,200) but there is no `tap` entry. Any ideas on how to get it working?

```
find /dev -name \*tap\*
```

finds nothing

```
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
kernel 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that `/dev/net/tun` is a universal tun/tap driver so there is nothing to load so long as you have the `tun` driver loaded.

```
ls /dev/net/tun
ls: cannot access /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory

ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
open: No such file or directory

modpobe tun
ls /dev/net/tun
/dev/net/tun

ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
```

Comment: click the tick then

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other answers work, check to make sure the line

```
alias char-major-10-200 tunode_tunnel
```

appears in `/lib/modules/.../modules.alias`